# Cast ray from the cursor and get the index of the hit face

Tags: python

Trying to find the simplest way to fire a ray from the mouse cursor and get just the face index of the intersected face. I'm looking through operator_modal_view3d_raycast.py, but getting the feeling that there's more going on there than I need. Is there an easier way, or should I stick with this course?

Comment: `operator_modal_view3d_raycast.py` had a bug in Orthograhic mode, which is fixed in 2.72 (next release, but you can grab a test build too). https://developer.blender.org/rB61baf6e8135d11bc53cbfa45c75f910a99e57971

Comment: I assume it's fixed if I build from source?

Comment: yep, if you build from current master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regarding **"but getting the feeling that there's more going on there than I need"**

This is too vague, you didn't state what you need.

There is [Scene.ray_cast](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast) - which you can use to ray-cast into the entire scene's visible objects, but this doesn't expose access to the face thats hit. (only the point of intersection & the normal)

In general, no, this can't be further simplified. you need to.

- Get the mouse coordinates from an Event.
- Get the RegionView3D from the context.
- Calculate a point-of-origin from the viewport *(not always obvious with orthographic projections)*
- Convert the mouse coordinates into a view-vector (using view3d_utils).
- loop over all objects you want to ray cast.
- convert the ray origin and direction into the object's local-space.
- run the ray-cast function on a selection of objects.
- find the closest result by shortening the ray each time.

Of course you can write your own function to handle all this, and just re-use. But there are many decisions involved in which objects are used, and how far to cast the ray, weather to use the views near-clip to offset the origin or not... etc.

If you don't need dupli-object support the script could be simplified to loop over scene-objects (but not duplicators).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to know. Converting between spaces is something I've put off learning for a long time. Guess it's time to finally dive in!

Comment: So, I thought I had this working but I've run into a snag. I'm using a (mostly) unmodified version of the raycast template from 2.72 master. Using it to select objects works exactly as expected, but the returned face index returns as None unless I select one specific object in the scene. I'm not sure what even determines which object this is, as I can add a cube and have the correct face returned, but if I duplicate that cube the second will select on click, but still return None as the face_index. If objects are alone in the scene they always return correctly. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: On this info alone, I wouldn't know why it fails, it would be good to see some test-case. to show the odd behavior.

Comment: The code I'm running is:

http://www.pasteall.org/54350/python

On LMB. As you can see I have a print function to tell what the face index is after picking an object, which works just fine with a single object visible, but fails with multiple visible objects. If I catch you on IRC I'll share the whole script and a .blend, but creating any scene with two objects and running that as an operator should give the same result.

Comment: Crushed the bug thanks to Aligorith. Turns out face_index is overwritten for each loop and I wasn't catching it. Was as simple as adding in a best_face = face_index after storing best_obj.